# Set Files LastWriteTime equal to another Files last Write time

Tags: powershell

I have 700,000 files in folder that were processed about a year ago so their LastWriteTimes are all from /mm/dd/2016.  We had to re-process all these files again due to an update to an image in the output file.  The files are in two separate directories but have the exact same file names.

My end users want me to update all the newly processed files to change the LastWriteTime to what the old processed files has.  This is for historical searching purposes.

I would like to use Powershell to the scan new folder ($dest) and update the new files LastWriteTime to match the old files LastWriteTime. My powershell is very rusty and ive gotten stuck and cant get by it and hoping for some help from a guru.

Here's the block of code that i started to develop.

```
$src = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\old"
$dest = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\new"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

   if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $nextName) 
    {
       Set-Item $dest.LastWriteTime = $src.LastWriteTime 
    }

}
```

Comment: `(Get-Item "D:\Path\newfile.txt").LastWriteTime = (Get-Item "D:\Path\oldfile.txt").LastWriteTime`

Comment: Thanks Bill, looks to be the solution i was looking for.

Comment: Do the files already exist in `\new`?  If not, there's a more efficient way than what you're doing

Comment: It seems to be grabbing a random date and not the LastWritetime date for the correct file.

Comment: They Do already exist in /new with the exact same file name.

Comment: That's an issue with your logic then.  You need to make sure the file/directory structure match before you write over the dates.

Comment: Im not sure i follow TheIncorrigible

Comment: It's not copying the proper write, because there's no error checking that you're comparing the same two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once recursing into subfolders your approach can't work.
Try this (untested)

```
$src  = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\old"
$dest = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\new"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $NewFullName = $_.Fullname -replace [RegEx]::Escape($src),$dest
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $NewFullName) {
       (Get-Item $NewFullName).LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
    }
}
```